# Auto close stories on all tasks completed

Tags: tfs

Our developers work from Sprint Boards, and they drag tasks into Closed stage. However, this leaves stories as New / Active when all tasks are done, and there is no easy way to know if story has all tasks completed

1. Is there a way to auto-close story when all tasks are done (without any additional plugins)?
2. Is there a way to identify what stories have all tasks closed/resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work items have independent states. Most of our experiences will not include automatic updates based on hierarchy. Either based on parent to update child or based on child to update parent.

You could refer Taylor's comment in this thread--[User Story status closed but child Task still active?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119677/user-story-status-closed-but-child-task-still-acti.html)

Even though there is not any build-in solution, you could use some 3-rd party tool to auto change parent states: [TFS Aggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator-webhooks) .

Another sample using Webhook to handle this.  Detail solution here: https://twitter.com/danhellem/status/1173614918333030400?s=20

which leads to: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions